# Styling Rewrite results in views

Tags: theming, views

I have a field in my view and I have rewritten the result (  `p align="left" [field_about_us_read_more]` ) and also check the "Output the field as a link". in styling setting section, "*Customize field HTML*" is "*None*" and "*Customize field and label wrapper HTML*" is "*DIV*"
the html code generated is like this:

```
<div>
    <a href="/www.com/test"></a>
    <p align="left">
        <a href="/www.com/test"> read more </a>
    </p>
</div>
```

How can I get rid of the first anchor link?
and how to add extra html element in the " *styling setting* ".

TNX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove check from  "Output the field as a link" and then in rewritten the result
put this

```
<p align="left">
        [field_about_us_read_more] 
    </p>
```

or if not work try something like this  (I mean in output use  tag )

```
   <p align="left">
 <a href="/www.com/test">[field_about_us_read_more]  </a>

        </p>
```